# Remove GRUB bootloader from EFI

Tags: ubuntu, grub, uefi

On Ubuntu 20.04, I want to remove the EFI bootloader installed by the default GRUB. Basically, I'm searching for the inverse of `grub-install`, which does not leave any dysfunctional remains (files on EFI partition, NVRAM entry, etc.) behind.

- I don't want to uninstall GRUB packages
- I don't want to uninstall Linux
- I don't have Windows
- There are other operating systems installed on the same drive with their own EFI bootloaders which must remain unaffected

I did not find a command like `grub-uninstall`, but there has to be some easy way, right?

Comment: `efibootmgr` does that. Google how to use it in case you have troubles understanding its manual. You may want to delete Ubuntu files in `/efi/EFI/...`

Comment: If you have another boot loader. Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader You may want to remove the mount of the ESP in fstab, so a major grub update does not reinstall it.

Answer (score 6):

*Its not like the space ocupied in the EFI partition by grub is huge, in my case in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/` occupies 4.4 MB....*

Perhaps if the bootloader is just bothering you could use:

### Recommended Alternatives

1. Use [`efibootmgr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/efibootmgr.8.html) to manage the boot options

```
:~$ efibootmgr

BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0003,0004,0005
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0003* rEFInd bootmgr
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0005* ubuntu
```

2. **Change the Boot Order**

```
:~$ sudo efibootmgr --bootorder 0003,0000,0004,0005

BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0004,0005
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0003* rEFInd bootmgr
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0005* ubuntu
```

3. **Deactivate a specific boot**

```
:~$ sudo efibootmgr --bootnum 0000 --inactive

BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0004,0005
Boot0000  ubuntu
Boot0003* rEFInd bootmgr
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0005* ubuntu
```

### To actually remove what is in the EFI

1. First we need to know where the ESP is mounted. Lets investigate. *Under Linux, the ESP is usually mounted at `/boot/efi`, although sometimes at `/boot`, or `/efi`. Under macOS or windows the ESP is not mounted by default, so you must mount it yourself to access it.[...more info here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#adjusting)*

```
:~$ sudo fdisk -l | grep -i efi
/dev/sda2    1024000   1638399    614400  300M EFI System
:~$ df | grep -i sda2
/dev/sda2         303104   113684    189420  38% /boot/efi
```

2. To access the `EFI` boot section we need to access as **superuser**

   a. normally you would do this with `su`

   b. Ubuntu has the `su` account locked so you would enter as `sudo -s`

```
username@nodename:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for username: 
root@nodename:/home/username# cd /boot/efi/
root@nodename:/boot/efi#
```

3. Search for where grub is:

```
:/boot/efi# find . -iname *grub*
./EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
./EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
```

4. I would suggest to make a backup copy.

   a. `cp -r ./EFI/ubuntu /home/username/tmp/ubuntu`

   b. the files copied will have `root` as owner, to be able to access them you will need to change their ownership with `sudo chown username -R /home/username/tmp/ubuntu/`
5. Now that you have a backup copy and determined that it is in `./EFI/ubuntu/...` its upto you to delete what you want... `rm -r ./EFI/ubuntu/`

*Best of Luck :)*

*P.S. I know I answered like 5 months late, but this was one of the first search engine matches , so I decided to give it an answer after I figured my own one out*

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same question after installing GRUB with EFI following the instruction [here](https://jacci.net/linux/pop-os/how-to-install-grub-on-pop-os-20-04/).

So if you are not satisfied with GRUB, then simply go back to Grub Customizer and change the `OUTPUT_FILE` back to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. I also removed `/boot/efi/EFI/pop/grubx64.efi` but I guess that's fine.
Everything works like a charm for me!